# Installation of R on redhat8 offline

Tags: r, linux, installation

I'm trying to have a way to download R for multiple clients with no internet access. Is there a way to download the .tar.gz files for all of R and its dependencies, so you don't need to download with internet connection? If there is a way to do that will R still show up with the "whereis R" command on linux? I'm trying to find a way in which I can give someone the downloaded files already within a package and they just run a .sh script that will download everything and R's dependencies for them with no real user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the manual on the topic "installing R under Unix-alike". Briefly: download the source and make it.

### Download R and untar it

You can download the source from:

https://cran.r-project.org/sources.html

Then, use "tar" to extract the source and build it. Let's suppose that you want to install R 4.2:

```bash
  tar -xf R-4.2.0.tar.gz
```

### Make

Go to a directory where you will install R. Note that the path shouldn't contain spaces.

```bash
  ./configure
  make
```

```bash
  make check
```

If you want to install all the R tree (binaries, manuals, libraries...) use:

```bash
  make install
```

### Installing packages from source

To install packages in R, you can use the function `install.packages()` with the name of the file ('...tar.gz') to be installed and the argument "repos" set as "NULL"

You can also install the packages from a shell:

```bash
  R CMD INSTALL -l /path/to/library packagename
```

### Check the manual for additional information

You may also be interested in looking at this information:

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/redhat/
- https://cran.r-project.org/sources.html
- The R manual describes how to install R from source in:

  - R-admin > Obtaining R > Getting and unpacking the sources
  - R-admin > Installing R under Unix-alikes